# Extracting numbers from a file

Tags: java, graph

My assignment is to create an adj. matrix for a graph from a file.
I am good up to reading line by line, not sure how to extract the numbers.

I wanted to do a for loop with index 0 to length-1 and see if charAt(i) is number or not.
However I am not sure how to do this. Any other ways of doing it would be appreciated.

I tried:

```
for (int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++){
  ch=s.charAt(i);

  if (ch !=" "){

  }
}
```

Compiler said its not a valid argument.

The format of the lines is vertices separated by one or more spaces.

If its possible to do this without any built in APIs it would be best.

UPDATE:
1) As Abbath suggested splitting would work but looking further into guidelines I see that it is not a guarantee that the file is well formed.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Remember that with String objects you need to use the .equals() method for comparison, using == or != compares references which is not what you are trying to do

Comment: If the file is guaranteed to be well formed, then using an initial split("  ")(two spaces here) to capture the pair and then a further split(" ") to capture each element of the pair could be another way to do it.

Comment: Abbath I just realized that I cant  be sure that the file is well defined.

Comment: @Voltizar Please expand and clarify your question.  1) What exactly does the compiler say is wrong with your code?  I'd suspect you mean't to write `ch != ' '` (note the single quotes) but you need to explain what error(s) you're seeing.  2) What do you mean the file may not be well defined?  If it's not well defined, it can't be parsed (since it could contain any content at all).  You say the file consists of lines of space separated numbers, is that not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you split a read line once, and then extract the numbers from it by passing the stored elements one by one to the method below. It checks if a String can be converted to a numeric value or not:

```
public boolean isNumeric(String s) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: PERFECT. excally what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed you can use Scanner to read the file and then access you numbers by scan.nextInt() or double or whatever type you use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestion. 
Using :
size = Integer.parseInt(s);

solved all my problems.